# iterrows faster alternative if data cannot be vectorized

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy, python-itertools

I am having a performance issue while implementing `iterrows()`.
My code is something like

```
for _, row in df.iterrows():
    row["new_col"] = \
        df.apply(lambda x:some_func(row["col1"], ...), axis=1)
```

`some_func()` is a kind of complicated function and cannot take input as `Series` and `DataFrame` requiring some specific value from the same row.

However, increasing number of rows increases time to process data exponentially, not linearly.

Is there some suggestion on how to speed it up? Probably splitting into smaller groups may improve or using something else instead of `iterrow()`.

Any comment is appreciated.

EDIT 1.

```
for count, row in df.iterrows():
    df.loc[count, "new_col"] = some_func(row["col1"], ... )
```

Comment: It depends of `complicated function`, what is reason for loop by `iterrows` and then loop in `apply` ?

Comment: from your code need for each row loop by all rows in original DataFrame by `df.apply(lambda x:...` ?

Comment: Should just be `df['new_col'] = df.apply(lambda x: some_func(x['col1'], ...), axis=1)`.

Comment: @jezrael The reason I am using ```iterrows``` is because I have to iterare over each cell of row while using the input from the same row and not being able to use vectors due to function limitation. I am thinking to rewrite my function, but that might be very complicated. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: @loamoza - comment means remove `for _, row in df.iterrows():` an use only `df['new_col'] = df.apply(lambda x: some_func(x['col1'], ...), axis=1)`

Comment: @loamoza no, you don't need `iterrows` here. Notice the `df['new_col']` in my comment. `apply` helps you align all the cells.

Comment: you might be interested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24870953/does-pandas-iterrows-have-performance-issues).

Comment: @QuangHoang You are right! I have just fixed the problem. I am adding my solution in the next edit.

Comment: You are still using `for loop`. The `apply` itself is a `for loop` in a way. So either use `apply` alone or use `for loop` alone. So far your problem can be solved by Quang Hoang comment. You editted your question but still included the for loop. Remove/delete the for loop. The solution in the comment is Sufficient

Comment: And as @jezrael pointed, it depends on `some_func`. Often complex functions can be simplified to a composition of trivial functions. If not, you can try to [numba](https://numba.pydata.org/)-it.

Comment: And BTW, just to be pedantic, _"if data cannot be vectorized"_ is wrong. Data is a vector/matrix already. What cannot be vectorized is the function.

Answer (score 0):

For the test purpose assume that your function is:

```
def some_func(c1, c2, c3, c4, c5):
    return c2 + c4 + 100
```

The test *DataFrame* I defined as:

```
   col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
0     1     2     3     4     5
1     6     7     8     9    10
2    11    12    13    14    15
```

If your function can receive neither a *DataFrame* nor a *Series*,
you can write an "adapter function":

```
def myAdapter(row):
    return some_func(*row[:5])
```

I put *[:5]* to allow that your DataFrame has some "additional" columns.
Then *some_func* is still called with values from first 5 columns of the
source row.

And to generate the new column in *df*, run:

```
df['new_col'] = df.apply(myAdapter, raw=True, axis=1)
```

`raw=True` causes that the argument passed to *myAdapter* (the current row)
is actually passed as a *Numpy* array, instead of pandasonic *Series*.

Its elements can be referred to by integer indices and while calling *some_func*,
it is possible to perform "list expansion" (concesutive elements of *row*
are passed as consecutive parameters of *some_func*

For my test data, the result is:

```
   col1  col2  col3  col4  col5  new_col
0     1     2     3     4     5      106
1     6     7     8     9    10      116
2    11    12    13    14    15      126
```

This way you have at least this gain that the execution time does not increase exponentially.
And in my opinion it should execute faster than your code.